# How to send dhcpd lease & MAC address info to central syslog server?

Tags: syslog, dhcpd

I am looking to send dhcpd leases including MAC address info etc. to my remote central syslog server, the server running dhcpd is running syslog-ng...would someone be so gracious as to assist me with some guidance on how to configure this properly in the dhcpd.conf and/or syslog-ng.conf?

Currently all logs on this server running dhcpd are configured via syslog-ng.conf to send to my central syslog server but I'm not getting the lease and detailed MAC address info etc that I am looking for...only very sparse logs with random source IP's only.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Could you post your current config? It sounds like your logging may be set to only send a certain level of events, rather than all events.

Comment: My dhcpd.conf is rather complex, in my dhcpd.conf there is no reference to any log-facility configuration, I was considering adding this then in my syslog-ng.conf (since all the logs are globally configured to log to my central syslog server here already) I was then going to add a line in syslog-ng.conf similar to the following hoping it would then shuve everything in local7 off to my central syslog server...does this sound proper?

In dhcpd.conf:

`log-facility local7;`

In syslog-ng.conf:

`local7.debug             /var/log/dhcpd.log`

Comment: My only issue is that I don't believe this gives me the lease information and MAC address information, from what I've read this is stored in /etc/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases so how do I get the lease information stored in dhcpd.leases pushed off to my central syslog server?